# How to determine the number of thread for each user in Jetty

Tags: performance, unit-testing, testing, embedded-jetty

When I look into Jetty. I see this sentence and as a newbie for Jetty.

> Load generators should be written in asynchronous programming style, so that limited threads does not limit the maximum number of users that can be simulated. If the generator is not asynchronous, **then a thread pool of 2000 may only be able to simulate 500 or less users**. The Jetty HttpClient is an ideal basis for building a load generator, as it is asynchronous and can be used to simulate many thousands of connections (see the Cometd Load Tester for a good example of a realistic load generator).

I wonder how to  determine the How to determine the number of thread for each user in Jetty.

Since I don't know how to test and which tool should I use.
Any hint will be appreciated.

Please.

Answer (score 0):

The number of threads you will require depends on the kind of load your application will need.

A typical web page is currently about 30 resources totaling about 40 MB that need to be requested for the web page to be "complete" and can be rendered fully.

If you use HTTP/2, which will get data faster, you will have a greater demand on the thread pool than if you use HTTP/1.1.

But lets say you need Jetty to supply data to a mobile chess playing app, less connections overall, you now have a much lower demand of threads per user.

The advice is as it always is, monitor your applications behavior, now, and in testing, and in QA, and in production.  Learn the behavior, and adjust your configuration accordingly.

It is impossible to "do the math" and set the perfect configuration up front without monitoring.  You will be adjusting these configurations over time as your application evolves and you learn more about the behaviors within your application.

Comment: Could you please introduce me some tuts about monitoring and testing and QA? Because I have no clue where to start. Many thanks to you.

Comment: Enable JMX, and start paying attention to the Eclipse Jetty information presented to you in the JMX console of your choice (example: jmc, or older jconsole).  Learn about JMX, and you'll even be able to have the information pulled automatically for your monitoring efforts during all things, local testing, QA, production, etc.   JMX in production is common, and is generally safe as long as you have proper permissions set for your JMX ports on the JVM that Jetty is running on.